# Why my angular controller don´t find my form - $scope.form undefined

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying do understand why my form is not recognize inside the maincontroller, if I put another controller outside, my form is recognize.

***config.js***

```
var myApp = angular.module('Myapp', ['ui.router','oc.lazyLoad','ui.bootstrap','kendo.directives','ngStorage',]);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/main");
    $stateProvider
        .state('testing', {
            url: "/testing",
            controller: 'MyController',
            templateUrl: "testing.html"
        });
}

angular
    .module('Myapp')
    .config(config)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

***MyController.js***

```
function MyController($scope) {     
  //do something
  $scope.test = {name: 'das'};

    $scope.sendTest = function () {
        console.log($scope.form.$valid);
        console.log($scope.form.testNumber.$valid);
        console.log($scope.form.testName.$valid);
    };
};

angular
    .module('Myapp')
    .controller('MyController', ["$scope"]);
```

***testing.html***

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <p>
        <label>Number: </label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="10" ng-model="test.number" name="testNumber" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.name" name="testName" required />
    </p>
    <button ng-click="sendTest()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Like this a have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined

but if I create another controller inside *MyController.js* and i move the code inside like this

```
function ChildController($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.test = {
        name: 'das'
    };

    $scope.sendTest = function () {
        console.log($scope.form.$valid);
        console.log($scope.form.testNumber.$valid);
        console.log($scope.form.testName.$valid);
    };
};

function MyController($scope) {  //do other stuff ...};


angular
    .module('Myapp')
    .controller('ChildController', ["$scope", ChildController])
    .controller('MyController', ["$scope"]);
```

and add the ng-controller to the form like this

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-controller='ChildController'>
```

the form is reconize correctly and working.

Can anyone explain what I am missing here, i would like to understand better, I am a novice.

Thanks you for the help.

Best regards.
Jolynice

Comment: Did you put ```ng-controller='MyController'```anywhere ?

Comment: Looks like its bound via the route.

Comment: Hello Komo and Sean. I don´t have ng-controller = 'MyController', the declaration is only in route controller: 'MyController',

Comment: The form's getting created on a child scope (not your controller's scope). The easiest way to fix would be to move to the "Controller As" syntax, but another way would be to create an empty vm on your scope - `$scope.forms = {};` and then reference a child of that from your markup: `ng-form="forms.form"`

Comment: first of all let me express my gratitude for all the help i am receiving, is my first post, and i was not expecting so quickly answers. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in Brad Barber's comment:

> The form is being created on the child scope and not the controller
>   scope.

A good solution like he suggested would be to add the `bindToController` and `controllerAs` syntax to your route object:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/main");
    $stateProvider
        .state('testing', {
            url: "/testing",
            controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'viewCtrl',
            bindToController: 'true',
            templateUrl: "testing.html"
        });
}
```

Now you can bind the name of the form as `viewCtrl.form`:

```
<form name="viewCtrl.form" novalidate>
    <p>
        <label>Number: </label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="10" ng-model="viewCtrl.test.number" name="testNumber" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="viewCtrl.test.name" name="testName" required />
    </p>
    <button ng-click="viewCtrl.sendTest()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can then notate it in your controller using `this`:

```
function MyController($scope) {     
  // Adding variables functions available to ctrl scope
  // same as vm = this;
  angular.extend(this, {
    test: {name: 'das'},
    sendTest: function() {
       console.log(this.form.$valid);
       console.log(this.form.testNumber.$valid);
       console.log(this.form.testName.$valid);
    }
  });

};

angular
    .module('Myapp')
    .controller('MyController', ["$scope", MyController]);
```

[Here is a codepen that I hacked together for you:](http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/EVMXpj)

Comment: Hi Sean, thank for your anwser, but i think i am missing something, I´ve done like you said, but nothing appens. no error .. nada .. lol , if is not to much to ask, can you create an example?

Comment: I'll attempt to, I have never do so before with ui-router in it. Give me a few moments.

Comment: I made a few changes to the code as there were some syntax issues. This should correspond to the codepen.

Comment: Thank you Sean, working well and now I understand.  5 stars ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether if the form is inside any div which has ng-if condition
Like

```
<div ng-if="condition">
  <form name="viewCtrl.form">
   .
  </form>
</div>
```

If this is so, the form would return undefined since there is new scope created for the DOM containing ng-if condition. Then use ng-show instead of ng-if that would not create new scope. I got this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648638/angularjs-form-inside-ng-if-not-accessible-from-controller)